# Is there a latex command \figuremark, analogous to \footnotemark?

Tags: latex, figure, pdflatex

I like using

```
\footnotemark
```

and

```
\footnotetext{}
```

(as described [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes))
for my footnotes, because it allows me to specify the exact position of the footnote while maintaining readability of my latex code.

Is there a common command which does something similar for figures? Something like:

```
\figuremark{label_ref}

\begin{figure}
  (my includegraphics, etc.)
  \label{label_ref}
\end{figure}
```

would give the same benefits for my figures.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of using `\footnotemark` implies a consecutive numbering within the text, regardless of where the `\footnotetext` might appear. Figures are different; they float around, and referencing them might not coincide exactly to where they are placed within the text. Moreover, they are quite substantial document elements and therefore deserve the preferential treatment of finding a place within the document that best fits the document, not necessarily the place-of-reference.

So, if you're interested in letting the float decide it's numbering *and* location, then you can use the regular `\label`-`\ref` system as in your example. Some renaming to achieve your requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\figuremark}{\ref}

\newcommand{\figuretext}{\caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

See Figures~\figuremark{fig:first}, \figuremark{fig:second} and~\figuremark{fig:third}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \figuretext{First figure}\label{fig:first}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \figuretext[ToC third figure]{Third figure}\label{fig:third}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \figuretext{Second figure}\label{fig:second}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

If you want the floats to land where they may (*i.e.* float) but fix the numbering to match your sequential referencing, then you can do something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\figuremark}[1]{\refstepcounter{figure}\label{#1}\thefigure}

\newcommand{\figuretext}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Make \refstepcounter a no-op
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\protect\ref{#1}}% Figure counter is actually a reference
  \caption
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

See Figures~\figuremark{fig:first}, \figuremark{fig:second} and~\figuremark{fig:third}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \figuretext{fig:first}{First figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \figuretext{fig:third}{Third figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \figuretext{fig:second}{Second figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

`\figuretext{<label>}` works just like `\caption` with the addition that you have to specify an accompanying `<label>` which will be used as a reference for your `\figuremark{<label>}`.

---

The advantage (benefit) of using the regular `\label`-`\ref` approach is that your float decides what happens, and that's how it should be. `\pageref`s will also be what one would expect; that is, the `\pageref` will point to the figure, not to where the figure was referenced.